# llama2-7B-chat taking very long to run and producing no response

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface, large-language-model, llama

I'm running the python 3 code below on ubuntu server 18.04 LTS.  I have a single nvidia gpu with 8GB of ram.  With the code below I am loading model weights and transformers I've downloaded from hugging face for the llama2-7b-chat model.  I'm trying to save as much memory as possible using bits and bytes.  I'm just trying to get a simple test response from the model to verify the code is working.  The code runs for a long time, nearly 20 minutes.  It doesn't return an error, but it also doesn't return any response.  It just returns the same prompt I passed it.  Does anyone see what the issue might be?  Since the model is so small and further optimized with bnb do I need to increase the temperature just to get a response?  Also does anyone have a suggestion how I can further optimize it so it doesn't take so long to run?

code:

````
import torch

# import hugging face apikey
from config import api_key

apikey=api_key

from torch import cuda, bfloat16
import transformers

model_id = 'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf'

device = f'cuda:{cuda.current_device()}' if cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

# set quantization configuration to load large model with less GPU memory
# this requires the `bitsandbytes` library
bnb_config = transformers.BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type='nf4',
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=bfloat16
)

# begin initializing HF items, need auth token for these
# hf_auth = '<YOUR_API_KEY>'

hf_auth = apikey
model_config = transformers.AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    use_auth_token=hf_auth
)

model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    trust_remote_code=True,
    config=model_config,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    device_map='auto',
    use_auth_token=hf_auth,
    cache_dir='/home/username/LLM/weights/huggingface/hub/'
)
model.eval()
print(f"Model loaded on {device}")


tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    use_auth_token=hf_auth
)


stop_list = ['\nHuman:', '\n```\n']

stop_token_ids = [tokenizer(x)['input_ids'] for x in stop_list]

stop_token_ids = [torch.LongTensor(x).to(device) for x in stop_token_ids]

from transformers import StoppingCriteria, StoppingCriteriaList

# define custom stopping criteria object
class StopOnTokens(StoppingCriteria):
    def __call__(self, input_ids: torch.LongTensor, scores: torch.FloatTensor, **kwargs) -> bool:
        for stop_ids in stop_token_ids:
            if torch.eq(input_ids[0][-len(stop_ids):], stop_ids).all():
                return True
        return False

stopping_criteria = StoppingCriteriaList([StopOnTokens()])


generate_text = transformers.pipeline(
    model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer,
    return_full_text=True,  # langchain expects the full text
    task='text-generation',
    # we pass model parameters here too
    stopping_criteria=stopping_criteria,  # without this model rambles during chat
    temperature=0.0,  # 'randomness' of outputs, 0.0 is the min and 1.0 the max
    max_new_tokens=512,  # mex number of tokens to generate in the output
    repetition_penalty=1.1  # without this output begins repeating
)


res = generate_text("Explain to me the difference between nuclear fission and fusion.")
print(res[0]["generated_text"])
````

output:

Explain to me the difference between nuclear fission and fusion.

Comment: Have you tried without stopping_criteria and repetition_penalty? I would give it a try to see if those two params cause the trouble. Is loading the model taking much time? You could try using a quantize model from HF.